# reduce output undefined while it probably shouldn't

Tags: javascript

Here's the thing, when I ran this code, it works fine:

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4];
arr.reduce(function(acc,val){
    if(val >= 2){
        acc['the key num ' + val + ' is'] = val;
    } 
    return acc;
},{});
```

But, when I try this one, it output undefined... I can't figure it out why.

```js
function ext(arr, zname) {
  arr.reduce(function(acc, val) {
    if (val[zname]) {
      acc = val[zname];
    }
    return acc;
  }, {});
}
console.log(ext([{
  name: "Alex",
  isTeacher: true
}, {
  name: "Bob",
  isTeacher: true
}, {
  name: "David",
  isTeacher: true
}], "name"))
```

It should output an object with the names, but instead I'm getting `undefined`

What am I missing here? :/

Comment: _"when I ran this code, it works fine"_ - The "working" code is a no-op as you're not doing anything with the return value of `.reduce()` (which would also be `undefined`)

Comment: Can you please provide your expected output? If you want all the names in an array, it might be a better idea to use `map` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing a `return` statement:

```js
function ext(arr, zname) {
  // |
  // V
  return arr.reduce(function(acc, val) {
    if (val[zname]) {
      acc.push(val[zname]);
    }
    return acc;
  }, []);
}
console.log(ext([{
  name: "Alex",
  isTeacher: true
}, {
  name: "Bob",
  isTeacher: true
}, {
  name: "David",
  isTeacher: true
}], "name"))
```

---

If you just want the names, that can be done more easily:

```js
const data = [{
  name: "Alex",
  isTeacher: true
}, {
  name: "Bob",
  isTeacher: true
}, {
  name: "David",
  isTeacher: true
}];

const ext = (arr, v) => arr.map(x => x[v]);

console.log(ext(data, "name"));
```

Comment: A little hard to spot in your answer. With regard to concise coding, it's good practice to do `return arr.reduce ...`, with regard to pointing out what is wrong; an additional line before the end of the function `return arr;` would make it easier to spot.

Comment: @connexo: Added a big arrow.

Comment: Thanks, but when I use the return like that, it doesn't output all the names... perhaps my condition is wrong?

Comment: @xewuy: That might be the case, the code is also different from you first example. But that is another issue of its own.

Comment: @xewuy: What should the function do?

Comment: `acc += val[zname] + '  ';`

Comment: @H.B. it should return something like:` ["Alex","Bob","David"]`. I should change also the `{}` in the condition of reduce to the `[]`, but what else? the `acc += val[zname] + ' ';` isn't it

Comment: @xewuy: Added a simple other example that achieves this. Should use `map` not `reduce`.

Comment: @H.B. I'm learning reduce :) I know how to achieve this with other methods, but can't get what is wrong with my code using the `reduce` :/

Comment: @xewuy: Adjusted `reduce` code as well. Got to push.

Comment: @H.B. OH... MY... GOD... ! M-an... now I feel super dumb :D I should've figure it out... because it's an array, that's why you need to push it... omfg... thanks man!

Comment: @xewuy: Haha, glad that helped :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const ext = (arr, zname) => {
  // Note: the use of `return` below
  return arr.reduce((acc, val) => {
    if (val[zname]) {
      acc = val[zname];
    }

    return acc;
  }, {});
}

console.log(ext([{
  name: "Alex",
  isTeacher: true
}, {
  name: "Bob",
  isTeacher: true
}, {
  name: "David",
  isTeacher: true
}], "name"))
```

You need to return the `reduce` function to get your result.

Comment: The last sentence should be _"You need to return the result of the `.reduce()` function"_ as you're not returning the `.reduce` function itself.

Answer (score 0):

The issues are fixed and commented in below code example.

You have another issue with the function you grabbed the code from - your data structure is not suited to create an object from it because an object can only have a maximum of one same-name property.

```js
function ext(arr, zname) {
  // you need to return the result of arr.reduce
  return arr.reduce(function(acc, val) {
    if (val[zname]) {
      // if you want a list of names, just push the names in acc
      acc.push(val[zname]);
    }
    return acc;
    // in that case initialize acc with [] instead of {}
  }, []);
}

console.log(ext([{
  name: "Alex",
  isTeacher: true
}, {
  name: "Bob",
  isTeacher: true
}, {
  name: "David",
  isTeacher: true
}], "name"))
```